# LiquiBase : is the SQL Code specified between <sql></sql> platform independent?

Tags: java, sql, database, liquibase

As mentioned in the tilte, I wonder if the sql code provided between the sql tag in Liquibase changeset is independent of the database type.I mean, is it refactored before executed to different DB Type ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever SQL code you put in is what is executed - Liquibase does not attempt to "translate" SQL from one database dialect to another. If you need custom SQL that works on multiple database platforms, you would need to write multiple custom sql changes and tag each one with the database that it applies to.

Comment: you mean like this : <sql dbms="mysql"></sql><sql dbms="oracle"></sql> ?